# Two-way ANOVA letters on barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova

i'm trying to display ANOVA letters for significant differences in multiple facet wrap indipendently.

```
Layer = c ("Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Glycaemia","Lept","Lept","Lept","Lyc","Lyc","Lyc","Toco","Toco","Toco","Total","Total","Total")
Treatment = c("Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","Before","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After","After")
ID = c("TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TS ","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","TCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","WCT","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","SWS (50%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)","WS (100%)")
Values = c(3.289816748,3.362127953,3.325972351,100.0640985,108.8993121,104.4817053,1134.911122,1185.17116,1160.041141,103.6375259,106.6489931,105.1432595,1267.848818,1238.265037,1297.4326,4.132191971,3.993355702,4.062773836,90.81362427,88.01775944,89.41569186,796.696971,761.9298358,779.3134034,84.66093913,82.57055679,83.61574796,872.7918691,891.6427873,853.940951,6.201027797,6.067398128,6.134212962,174.6704272,177.8458951,176.2581612,2237.943868,2201.916461,2219.930164,190.9631843,193.7692431,192.3662137,872.7918691,891.6427873,853.940951,7.569878554,7.707464928,7.638671741,230.0618153,236.2865172,233.1741662,3043.515264,3238.239271,3140.877268,263.0428396,267.6006213,265.3217305,3381.690106,3281.146958,3482.233253,6.702549805,6.788588011,6.745568908,158.0756379,171.517128,164.7963829,1650.889677,1721.998305,1686.443991,223.455185,233.136505,228.295845,1857.985943,1815.667864,1900.304021,9.139627531,8.865075894,9.002351712,25.77066923,24.59148277,25.181076,183.0059741,190.4796753,186.7428247,56.2845922,60.27195526,58.27827373,220.9262524,217.9162708,223.936234,15.64450382,16.51384377,16.07917379,35.88399637,34.82508889,35.35454263,137.5075624,137.0082927,137.2579275,97.29968158,89.45059985,93.37514072,188.6916439,189.0360626,188.3472253,10.89751715,11.12202557,11.00977136,14.09101053,16.37410946,15.23256,190.84397,206.4125253,198.6282476,65.37033935,70.1741487,67.77224403,224.870579,215.8324977,233.9086603,10.75874498,11.08587144,10.92230821,24.52723404,30.88047689,27.70385546,73.17145228,79.30175358,76.23660293,74.38943912,83.50818223,78.94881067,114.8627666,108.4574313,121.2681019,12.20495696,12.38610121,12.29552909,17.82967375,18.97451462,18.40209419,86.35822169,93.68197336,90.02009753,57.56973477,62.6560604,60.11289758,120.7177208,116.3928524,125.0425892)
prova=cbind(Layer, Treatment,Values, ID)
```

my otuput graph is:

```
library (dplyr) 

by_Group <-  prova %>% group_by(ID, Treatment, Layer)
SUM3<-summarise(by_Group, mean= mean(Value), sd=sd(Value))
ggplot(SUM3, aes(x=samples, y=mean,colour=Digesta, fill=Digesta), stat="identity", alpha=0.7) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5,position=position_dodge(0.7))+ facet_wrap(~Polyphenols, scales = "free_y")+
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=samples, ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=0.4, alpha=0.9, position=position_dodge(0.7), colour="black")+theme_pubr()+ scale_color_grey()+ scale_fill_grey()+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust=1, hjust=1), axis.title.x = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())+ylab(label="µg/g DW")
```

How can i add letters from 2-way ANOVA in each facet indipendentely?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide  the dataframe called prova.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it in the first part of the question